# url_for inside include with jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm using flask with a jinja2 template which includes another jinja2 template called buttons.html.

The parent of the buttons template looks like this:

```
{% include "{{ url_for('.buttons') }}" %}
```

The blueprint code looks like this:

```
@whatever_blueprint.route('/whatever/buttons.html', methods=['GET'])
def buttons():
    return render_template('/whatever/buttons.html')
```

This allows me to take advantage of the fact that jinja will resolve the . prefixed url_for path to the current blueprint context and thus give me buttons rendered specifically for the blueprint in which this is rendered. I use the .prefix method in other cases, but haven't tried the nested url_for in this context. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get this to work, presumably because of the nested {% {{ }} %}.

Is this possible?

Comment: what is the dot (' .buttons ') for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately (or fortunately? most use-cases would be rather ugly) you cannot include URLs but only templates.

What you want is `{{ buttons() }}` with `buttons` being the `buttons` function (or `{{ buttons }}` with `buttons=buttons()` in `render_template()`) passed to the `render_template()` call or made available via the global template context.